# How to switch audio output modes between stereo and mono in android programmatically?

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack

Actually I am trying to make a custom music player application,in which i just wanted to provide users a chance to change audio output to stereo and mono.

Answer (score 2):

You can set when you make a instance of `AudioTrack`.

```
    /* Create AudioTrack instance */
    AudioTrack mAudioTrack = null;

    int minSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(
            16000,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, // or set AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    if (mAudioTrack == null) {
        mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                16000,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, // or set AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                minSize,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    }
    /* Create AudioTrack instance */

    /* Stop and release AudioTrack instance */
    mAudioTrack.flush();
    mAudioTrack.stop();
    mAudioTrack.release();
    mAudioTrack = null;
    /* Stop and release AudioTrack instance */
```

If you want to make new instance of `AudioTrack` in runtime, previous instance will be released first.

Comment: Thank you for your response@Kae10...But I have tried it already with different frequency.i.e.,22050,48000 also.but it is not working.

Comment: Could you check the logs about `AudioTrack` or your problems? Your sampleRate isn't illegal, but in some cases, it is not proper value.

Comment: Hmm... Could you update your module? Also, I want to know there is any problem when you play music.

Comment: There is no problem while I am playing music.Just output seems to be not changing..Actually not only in music player but it should also be updated in the system media settings too.Same thing I have done as you suggested.@Kae10